# Android Eclipse boots up into emulator, but I need it to display Hello World

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I launch the android emulator, it takes a few minutes to start and after some time, i get the splash screen, then i get the whole emulator running...

I can "swipe" with my mouse to unlock, and it shows a clock, 3-4 apps, home button, etc.

But I need it to only display hello world..and it doesn't.

```
I do get the following in the console

[2013-09-15 06:43:06 - AndrdLove] ------------------------------
[2013-09-15 06:43:06 - AndrdLove] Android Launch!
[2013-09-15 06:43:06 - AndrdLove] adb is running normally.
[2013-09-15 06:43:06 - AndrdLove] Performing com.example.andrdlove.FullscreenActivity activity launch
[2013-09-15 06:43:06 - AndrdLove] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'standard'
[2013-09-15 06:43:06 - AndrdLove] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'standard'
[2013-09-15 06:43:08 - AndrdLove] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-09-15 06:43:08 - AndrdLove] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-09-15 06:47:08 - AndrdLove] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-09-15 06:47:08 - AndrdLove] Uploading AndrdLove.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-09-15 06:47:08 - AndrdLove] Installing AndrdLove.apk...
[2013-09-15 06:48:34 - AndrdLove] Success!
[2013-09-15 06:48:34 - AndrdLove] Failed to install AndrdLove.apk on device 'emulator-5554': device not found
[2013-09-15 06:48:34 - AndrdLove] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: device not found
[2013-09-15 06:48:34 - AndrdLove] Launch canceled!
```

EDIT: Please note, this question is NOT a duplicate.

My problem is rare and I cannot find an easy solution using google. I have tried.

To better explain my problem...
I see people who have an issue launching android emulator.
That is not my issue. The emulator launches... and it goes to the Home screen. 
At the home screen, there is a Lock.. when I swipe it, it opens up the emulator and there are 4 apps there. 
Working as intended right?
Right, except that I don't want that. 
I want the emulator to show  an empty "Hello world" message just like my tutorial suggests.

I FINALLY figured it out.

What I had to do was go to the `values` folder. Double click on `strings.xml` and there I could either add or change or keep the value of the string. However, if I wanted it to show when I "unlocked" the phone, I had to Move up the Resource elemetns. 
I have the option of `Add` `Remove` `Up` `Down`. I selected the `hello_world(string)` element and moved it `up` to the top.

Went to the launch icon, clicked `run configuration` selected `Android application` and when a window pops up, it will have an empty project field. Right next to the field is the `browse` button, click it and select your application project name. Then simply click `Run`.

Phew.

Comment: I have voted to reopen so you can answer and accept you own question.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the emulator has the "USB debugging enabled" tooltip in the notification area. If it doesn't, then it can be solved by simply recreating the emulator.

For some reason my emulators tend to stop connecting to ADB every now and then, and I have to recreate them to fix the problem.